# learning_ps3joy

Tags: ros, tutorial, ps3joy, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am setting up a ps3 joystick, according to the ps3joy tutorial - [WritingTeleopNode](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ps3joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode).

I have followed the instructions and built the sample code for the teleop_turtle_joy.cpp.

I also created the sample launch file.  However, I am not sure how to run this.  When I try:
`roslaunch learning_ps3joy turtleps3joy.launch`

I get the error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ps3joy/ps3_joy_node]: Cannot locate node of type [ps3_joy_node] in package [ps3joy]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [turtle_teleop/turtle_teleop_joy]: Cannot locate installation of package turtle_teleop: [rospack] couldn't find package [turtle_teleop]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/turtlebot/tutorials/workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks]
```

This is using ROS Electric on Ubuntu 10.04 lucid.
Any suggestions would be helpful.  I just want to control the bot with the Ps3 joystick.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12949/learning_ps3joy/) by [ceverett](https://answers.ros.org/users/1761/ceverett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 332 on 2012-02-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- Make sure you build your new package using `rosmake`, which will build the dependencies, including `ps3joy`, which will fix the first error
- Make sure you have the `turtle_teleop` package installed and on your ROS Path, which will likely fix the second error.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you.  I noticed the default launch file works fine. I didn't notice that in the tutorial.  I can now control the turtlebot with the ps3 joystick:
roslaunch turtlebot_teleop ps3_teleop.launch

---

Originally posted by [ceverett](https://answers.ros.org/users/1761/ceverett/) with karma: 332 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1